# How can I sort Columns by Row values?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

There are [too] many examples online of how to sort the **Rows** of a JTable by Column values.

Currently I am doing this by implementing `AbstractTableModel` and overridding `getColumnClass` to return the actual class of the data. Then calling `setAutoCreateRowSorter`.

How can I sort the **Columns** in a JTable by Row values?

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The above question is about sorting Rows, I want to sort Columns.

Comment: hmm .. don't quite understand what you are after, but as far as I do it's not supported in core: rows and columns are _not_ semantically exchangeable. There are frameworks which support pivot tables, maybe they can be used, either directly or for inspiration

Answer (score 5):

1) extract all value from `TableHeader` to the shortable Array (could be method in `AbstractTableModel`)

2) loop inside array and call

```
TableColumn column = table.getColumnModel().moveColumn(columnIndex, newIndex);
```

3) for all methods that used Model v.s. View (and vice versa) is required add

```
table/model#convertXxxIndexToXxx
```

4) for reset you have to create method in `AbstractTableModel` by calling

```
fireTableDataChanged(); or fireTableStructureChanged(); // not sure in this case
```

5) notice about above two fireTableXxxXxx

```
This can be a problem if you have added any custom renderers or editor to 
the table as you would lose them (by @camickr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just define and set the RowSorter on your JTable. Here's a simple tutorial:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting

Comment: I want to sort the Columns not the Rows. RowSorters sort the rows.

Answer (score -1):

You can sort the values by clicking on a column header, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: I want to sort the Columns. When you click on the header it sorts the Rows.

Comment: I think there is no built-in function for that. You should sort by yourself, obtain the indexes and reset the column positions.

Comment: You can probably achieve that by implementing a hacked version of TableModel.